# In Reporting Services, how to use SOAP API to acquire the list of accessible reports for one authenticated user?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I'm asked to implement an ASP.net page for domain users to access their accessible reports, and hidden all unauthorized reports. I've checked the MS SSRS Web Service API document for that, but still can't figure it out. Please kindly advise, any idea is appreciated.

My development environment is using SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 and Vistual Studio 2008.

Thanks!
William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim rs As ReportingService
rs = New ReportingService()
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
Dim items() As CatalogItem

items = rs.ListChildren("/", False)
```

I found myself that, the ListChildren() will populate a list of objects that are only accessible from the authenticated and authorized user.